# How to iterate through a JSON response with nested arrays/lists

Tags: c#, arrays, json, unity-game-engine, object

I'm working on a project where the API returns a JSON response with nested Array Objects. I've tried to loop through to get the inner most array of string (Hex) items. But the item shows as null.

Here is the JSON response: I'm trying to access the main part below, which is an array of string hex bytes.

```
{   // The main response
    "Success": true,
    "Total": 49,
    "TotalPages": 49,
    "ModesList": [
        {
            "Id": 1058,
            "Name": "kharabeesh",
            "Order": 0,
            "StepOneTime": "2.03s",
            "UserId": 1015,
            "IsPublic": true,
            "User": "Sahar M",
            "Date": "02/06/2021",
            "Mode": [ // I'm trying to access this part
                [
                    "16",
                    "1",
                    "1",
                    "0",
                    "5",
                    "71",
                    "255",
                    "255",
                    "255",
                    "76",
                    "20"
                ],
                [
                    "16",
                    "2",
                    "1",
                    "6",
                    "53",
                    "71",
                    "76",
                    "3",
                    "33",
                    "0",
                    "17"
                ],
                [
                    "16",
                    "3",
                    "1",
                    "6",
                    "53",
                    "71",
                    "73",
                    "127",
                    "87",
                    "0",
                    "17"
                ],
                [
                    "16",
                    "4",
                    "1",
                    "7",
                    "181",
                    "127",
                    "127",
                    "119",
                    "45",
                    "0",
                    "17"
                ],
                [
                    "16",
                    "5",
                    "1",
                    "0",
                    "7",
                    "192",
                    "170",
                    "48",
                    "11",
                    "0",
                    "32"
                ],
                [
                    "16",
                    "6",
                    "1",
                    "7",
                    "130",
                    "15",
                    "67",
                    "71",
                    "170",
                    "0",
                    "32"
                ],
                [
                    "16",
                    "7",
                    "1",
                    "0",
                    "67",
                    "8",
                    "206",
                    "45",
                    "195",
                    "0",
                    "68"
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class GetModesResponse
    {
        public bool Success;
        public long Total;
        public long TotalPages;
        public List<ModesList>[] ModesList;
    }

    public class ModesList
    {
        public long Id;
        public string Name;
        public long Order;
        public string StepOneTime;
        public long UserId;
        public bool IsPublic;
        public string User;
        public string Date;
        public List<long>[] Mode;
    }

private void PopulateModes(GetModesResponse publicModes)
    {
        var allModes = publicModes.ModesList;
        var index = 0;
        foreach(var mode in allModes[0])
        {
            Debug.Log(mode.Name);
            var modeItem = Instantiate(ModeItemPrefab, ModeContainer.transform);
            var usedColors = new List<Color>();
            var steps = mode.Mode[0];
            Debug.Log(steps[0]);
            var stepColor = mainScript.GetColor((byte) steps[6], (byte) steps[7], (byte) steps[8], (byte) steps[9], 0);
            if (!usedColors.Contains(stepColor))
            {
                usedColors.Add(stepColor);
            }
            modeItem.Initialize(index, (int) mode.Id, mode.Name, mode.User, usedColors, this);
        }
    }
```

### Update

This is how I call the populate function after getting the JSON from the API:

```
private IEnumerator GetPublicModes()
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("keyword", "");
        form.AddField("size", 1000);
        form.AddField("pageNo", 1);
        
        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(Manager.ApiUrlBase + "GetModes", form))
        {
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();
            if (!www.isDone)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
            }
            else
            {
                var response = www.downloadHandler.text;
                Debug.Log("Get Modes complete!");
                GetModesResponse getModesResponse = new GetModesResponse();
                getModesResponse = JsonUtility.FromJson<GetModesResponse>(response);
                Debug.Log(getModesResponse.ToString());
                if (getModesResponse.Success)
                {
                    //Populate List
                    gottenModes = getModesResponse;
                    PopulateModes(getModesResponse);
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    // Display Error Message
                    Debug.Log(response);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

UPDATE Solution:
Thank you @MajidMohammadi, @AttilaMolnar, @A_____, and @derHugo for your help. @derHugo helped me find the answer by going to https://json2csharp.com/ it finally worked. Here is how I did it in the end:

```
[Serializable] 
    public class ModesList
    {
        public ModesList(
            int id,
            string name,
            int order,
            string stepOneTime,
            int userId,
            bool isPublic,
            string user,
            string date,
            List<List<string>> mode
        )
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.Name = name;
            this.Order = order;
            this.StepOneTime = stepOneTime;
            this.UserId = userId;
            this.IsPublic = isPublic;
            this.User = user;
            this.Date = date;
            this.Mode = mode;
        }

        public int Id;
        public string Name;
        public int Order;
        public string StepOneTime;
        public int UserId;
        public bool IsPublic;
        public string User;
        public string Date;
        public List<List<string>> Mode;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class GetModesResponse
    {
        public GetModesResponse(
            bool success,
            int total,
            int totalPages,
            List<ModesList> modesList
        )
        {
            this.Success = success;
            this.Total = total;
            this.TotalPages = totalPages;
            this.ModesList = modesList;
        }

        public bool Success;
        public int Total;
        public int TotalPages;
        public List<ModesList> ModesList;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried change type of Mode property to the array of bytes(=byte[ ])?

Comment: No, I haven't, how would that look?

Comment: After I see exactly your code, I came to the conclusion that you might need change the type of Mode property to the type of byte[ ][ ](= array of byte array). I hope it resolve the problem.

Comment: Thanks you @Majid Mohammadi, but that didn't change anything unfortunatly. I'm still getting this error: 

`NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
GalleryPanelScript.PopulateModes (GalleryPanelScript+GetModesResponse publicModes) (at Assets/Scripts/GalleryPanelScript.cs:83)`

 which is this part of the code:  `foreach(var mode in allModes[0])`

Comment: I think, `public List<ModesList>[] ModesList;` should only be `public List<ModesList> ModesList;`,  as ModeList is just a simple list not a nested list. 


And when you specified this in the other model `public List<long>[] Mode;` I am not sure it can be true because numbers are in apostrophes ("), so from JSON syntax view they must be string not long (unless if you do not have any conversion function for that record). I would specify it on this way: `public List<List<string>> Mode;`

Comment: @AttilaMolnar, I'm using `int.Parse()` to convert to an int and cast as long, but I could just use int in the declaration, but that made no difference

Comment: @RobertH Have you tried to change this `public List<ModesList>[] ModesList;` to this `public List<ModesList> ModesList;`. I think it is the main problem because ModeList is just a list not a list of list in JSON. Of course some other changes are required due to this in your code, e.g. you need to change the foreach also by this change from `foreach(var mode in allModes[0])` to `foreach(var mode in allModes)`.

Comment: @RobertH Did you give null reference on whole `ModeList` or the `ModeList`'s Mode property?

Comment: @AttilaMolnar, it still give the same error if I make it `public List<ModesList> ModesList;` and change the foreach loop to your suggestion

Comment: @RobertH How do you deserialize the JSON? Using System.Text.Json, like `var myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);`?

Comment: @MajidMohammadi, yes on the whole ModeList I believe

Comment: @AttilaMolnar, I'm getting it like this:
`GetModesResponse getModesResponse = new GetModesResponse();
                getModesResponse = JsonUtility.FromJson<GetModesResponse>(response);`

Comment: It might be related to the line which you `Deserialize` the response.

Comment: @MajidMohammadi, I updated the question with the get function for the API

Comment: @RobertH In this line of code `var response = www.downloadHandler.text;` when you get response, it `ModeList` property has any items? when you debug the code, you can set watch the string as `json`.

Comment: @MajiedMohammadi yes, it’s the same like the JSON on the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general for working with Unity your classes should be marked [`[Serializable]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Serializable.html). See [Unity Script Serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html) for details.

And then what you have there in your JSON is not a `List<long>[]` but rather a `List<string>[]` or simply `List<List<string>>` since your numbers are wrapped in `"`!

So your class should look like e.g. ([json2csharp](https://json2csharp.com) often provides a very solid start point and requires only some little adoptions to work with the Unity serializer)

```
[Serializable]
public class ModesList
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public int Order;
    public string StepOneTime;
    public int UserId;
    public bool IsPublic;
    public string User;
    public string Date;
    public List<List<string>> Mode;
}

[Serializable]
public class GetModesResult
{
    public bool Success;
    public int Total;
    public int TotalPages;
    public List<ModesList> ModesList;
}
```

and then you would use [`byte.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.byte.parse) like e.g.

```
var stepColor = mainScript.GetColor(byte.Parse(steps[6]), byte.Parse(steps[7]), byte.Parse(steps[8]), byte.Parse(steps[9]), 0);
```

---

However, only on the phone right now so can't test it but further

> Note: Unity does not support serialization of multilevel types (multidimensional arrays, jagged arrays, and nested container types). If you want to serialize these, you have two options: wrap the nested type in a class or struct, or use serialization callbacks [`ISerializationCallbackReceiver`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ISerializationCallbackReceiver.html) to perform custom serialization. For more information, see documentation on [Custom Serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization-Custom.html).

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I then get the error: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. So how can I fix that?

Comment: When I loop through the ModesList.Mode and I put Debug.Log(step[0]) it prints in the console Null 7 times. So I'm unable to get the properties inside the list of Mode

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the structure of JSON.

I tested it locally:

The JSON file

```
{   
    "Success": true,
    "Total": 49,
    "TotalPages": 49,
    "ModesList": [
        {
            "Id": 1058,
            "Name": "kharabeesh",
            "Order": 0,
            "StepOneTime": "2.03s",
            "UserId": 1015,
            "IsPublic": true,
            "User": "Sahar M",
            "Date": "02/06/2021",
            "Mode": [
                {
                    "Value":
                    [   
                        "16",
                        "1",
                        "1",
                        "0",
                        "5",
                        "71",
                        "255",
                        "255",
                        "255",
                        "76",
                        "20"
                    ]   
                },
                {
                    "Value":
                    [    
                        "16",
                        "2",
                        "1",
                        "6",
                        "53",
                        "71",
                        "76",
                        "3",
                        "33",
                        "0",
                        "17"
                    ]   
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The DataModuleClass(C#)

```
[Serializable]
public class XXXDataModule
{
    public bool Success;
    public int Total;
    public int TotalPage;

    public List<ModesList> ModesList;

    public XXXDataModule()
    {
    }

}


[Serializable]
public class ModesList
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public int Order;
    public string StepOneTime;
    public int UserId;
    public bool IsPublic;
    public string User;
    public string Date;
    public List<Mode> Mode;

    public ModesList()
    {
        
    }
}


[Serializable]
public class Mode
{
    public Mode()
    {
        
    }

    public List<string> Value;
}
```

The Deserialization(C#)

```
    public void OnClickJsonParse()
    {
        // I just simulated the reading of the data locally
        var jsonText = File.ReadAllText(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/LitJson4Unity.json");
        Debug.Log("jsonText " + jsonText);

        //JsonData json = JsonMapper.ToObject(jsonText);

        // Use LitJson
        //XXXDataModule jsonData = JsonMapper.ToObject<XXXDataModule>(jsonText);

        // Use Unity JSONSerializeModule
        XXXDataModule jsonData = JsonUtility.FromJson<XXXDataModule>(jsonText);

        Debug.Log(jsonData.ModesList[0].Mode[0].Value[0]);

    }
```

[VS Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvAiw.png)

Comment: When you have server APIs changing the JSON is often not an option though ;)

Comment: In my case, it might be difficult to change it